# all parent elements moving when i hover the cursor on the child element

Tags: html, css

I have parent div and four child divs. the parent element is a container and child elements are buttons. I set the CSS property of the button to increase its border-width when I hover on it. the actual problem is whenever the button increases its border-width; the entire webpage moving. how can I make the webpage stable?

```css
#theme-options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.theme-button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
}

.theme-button:hover {
  border-width: 5px;
}

#light-mode {
  background-color: #ffff;
}

#blue-mode {
  background-color: #192734;
}

#green-mode {
  background-color: #78866b;
}

#purple-mode {
  background-color: #7e4c74;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-options-wrapper">
  <div data-mode="light" id="light-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="green" id="green-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="purple" id="purple-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="blue" id="blue-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
</div>
```

here the page URL link
https://nanthu0123.github.io/portfolio/

image of buttons (child elements)
[buttons-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A0hJ.png)

here the source code
https://github.com/nanthu0123/portfolio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*hey*, add **box-sizing: border-box;**  property to your ***.theme-button*** class.

#### UPDATE:

also if you want make your button larger add  **transform: scale(1.3);** to your pseudo class (**.theme-button:hover**)

Comment: I tried this property. but it does not allow to enlarge the button(for highlighting purpose) when I hover on it.

Comment: yes man.. the problem is fixed partially. movement of entire page has solved. but buttons are not resizing when hover.

Comment: wow, man.. thank you.. your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to simply not use the `border` to draw the border, instead use the `box-shadow` property, which can take a comma-separated list of `box-shadow` definitions; below I've added a 2-pixel 'fake border' after the definition of the original `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 2px #000;
```

And, within the `:hover` pseudo-class expanded that 2-pixel size to 5-pixels:

```
box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 5px #000;
```

As the box-shadow doesn't take space in the document it won't force elements to reflow (though obviously a repaint is required to show the changed shadow).

```css
#theme-options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.theme-button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 2px #000;
}

.theme-button:hover {
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 5px #000;
}

#light-mode {
  background-color: #ffff;
}

#blue-mode {
  background-color: #192734;
}

#green-mode {
  background-color: #78866b;
}

#purple-mode {
  background-color: #7e4c74;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-options-wrapper">
  <div data-mode="light" id="light-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="green" id="green-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="purple" id="purple-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="blue" id="blue-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
</div>
```

This can also be transitioned/animated – the colour, length or both – if required, with a single line:

```
transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
```

```css
#theme-options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.theme-button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 2px #000;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}

.theme-button:hover {
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), 0 0 0 5px #000;
}

#light-mode {
  background-color: #ffff;
}

#blue-mode {
  background-color: #192734;
}

#green-mode {
  background-color: #78866b;
}

#purple-mode {
  background-color: #7e4c74;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-options-wrapper">
  <div data-mode="light" id="light-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="green" id="green-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="purple" id="purple-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
  <div data-mode="blue" id="blue-mode" class="theme-button"></div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).
- [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: You're very welcome, please remember that if any of the answers have answered your question, please consider accepting that answer as the solution (by checking the grey check-Mark beside the relevant answer). If your question hasn't been answered adequately then edit your question to explain what's missing from existing answers. :)